# Urdf as a way to model dynamics?

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, dynamics, manipulator, redundant-robots

Since urdf format serves the purpose of kinematic model but also extends for dynamical properties such as mass,moment of inertia and centre of masses, can it be considered a viable dynamical model of a robot, comparable to standard methods such as Euler-Lagrange and Newton-Euler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. URDF is a convenient way to format information about the model; it is not a model itself.